# The properties of the sum of exponentials

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:
$$P > \sum \limits_{i=1}^ n \exp(a_i\cdot t)$$
where $a_i \in[0,1]$.

I'm trying to find $t$. I realize that there's no simple way to get the log of a sum, but I was wondering if there are relevant properties by which I can get rid of the sum, without completely "loosing" the values of $a_i$.
Perhaps something like:
$$P > \sum \limits_{i=1}^ n \exp(a_i\cdot t) > 
n \cdot \exp(\mathrm{ave}\cdot t)$$ 
where $\mathrm{ave}$ is the average of $a_i$, and therefore the expression is dependent on the values of $a_i$.

Or something of the sort.

Answer (score 1):

Since $a_i \le 1$, you have $\Bbb e ^{a_i t} \le \Bbb e ^t$, so the right-hand side is $\le n \Bbb e ^t$. Therefore, if you solve the stronger inequality $P > n \Bbb e ^t$ you will get $t < \ln \frac P n$. This solution also solves your original inequation (but the converse is not true: there might be solutions of the original inequation that do not solve this stricter one).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clear answer, but I'm looking for a tighter bound than that. I could do better with: 
n*e^t*a_max <= n*e^t
but I'm hoping for something closer to the average.